# (Symbolic Logic) Proving P v P = P (Idempotency) using a direct proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Ok, so it's very easy to show P v P = P (where = is logically equivalent) using a truth table as well as using a conditional proof.

1. P v P     Premise
2. ~p        Assumption
3. p         Disjunctive Syllogism (1, 2)
4. p & ~p    Conjunction (3, 4)
5. ~p --> (p & ~p)     CP (2--4)
6. p v ~p     EMI
7. ~p v p      Commutation (6)
8. ~p v ~~p     Double Negation (7)
9. ~(p & ~p)     De Morgan's (8)
10. ~~p     Modus Tollens (5, 9)
11. p     Double Negation

My question is, how do I show p v p = p WITHOUT using a truth table OR a conditional prove? I can only use the basic rules of inference (EMI, Disjunctive Syllogism, Addition, Conjunction, Simplification) as well as the rules of replacement (De Morgan's, Distribution, etc.)

Comment: which rules are allowed?

Comment: The basic rules of inference (EMI, Disjunctive Syllogism, Addition, Conjunction, Simplification) as well as all the rules of replacement (De Morgan's, Distribution, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a Copi exercise, so I'll use the rules in the 1998 edition of "Introduction to Logic".

1 [(p $\lor$ p)=(p $\lor$ p)] $\lor$ commutation

2 [(p $\lor$ p)=$\lnot$$\lnot$(p $\lor$ p)] 1 Double Negation

3 [(p $\lor$ p)=$\lnot$($\lnot$p $\land$ $\lnot$ p)] 2 De Morgan's ahem... Petrus Hispanus's Theorems

4 [(p $\lor$ p)=$\lnot$$\lnot$p] 3 $\land$ tautology

5 [(p $\lor$ p)=p]  4 Double Negation

Answer (score 2):

A normal proof would be:

```
1. P v P     Premise
2. |_ p      Assumption
3. |  P      2 reiteration 
4  p         1,2,3,2,3 v Elimination
```

Comment: You used conditional proof.

Comment: It is a Proof by Cases.

Answer (score 2):

(1) PvP

(2) <=> ~ (~P & ~P) ______________  By definition of OR :  (XvY) <=> ~ ( ~X & ~Y)

(3) <=> ~ ~P _____________________  By : idempotency of &

(4) <=> P  _______________________   By : double negation

Comment: What's wrong with my proof?

Comment: It looks reasonable to me.